# Android Video and voice call (WebRTC)

Tags: android, webrtc

I want to develop an android application on webRTC which allows video and voice call. I did research on this and come to know that I can implement using jingle library but there is no proper documentation about it and no example on how to implement. I want to use open source library. Please suggest some good documentations and examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news! there aren't much documentation yet.

Good news! but it will come soon I gamble.

Best starter template for android WebRTC that I could find so far is from [pristine.io](https://github.com/pristineio/apprtc-android) which is a mirror of the official Android AppRTC demo.

If you just wanna compile WebRTC library and build your android project from scratch simply add the latest build which is hosted by pristine.io and you can directly compile it in your gradle file. The current version that I am using is `io.pristine:libjingle:9456@aar`

I found this [tutorial](https://tech.appear.in/2015/05/25/Introduction-to-WebRTC-on-Android/) from 'appear in' extremely helpful to get familiar with android WebRTC development steps.

Comment: tutorial link gives 'Server not found'